# Cannot find module an external js whith fullpath after build a bundle whith Webpack and Babel in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, bundle

I build a bundle with all the needed resources with Webpack including node_modules because Im going to run this bundle in another place where the package.json and node_modules not exist, thats the reason why Im building the bundle including node_modules.

In some moment, the bundle needs to require an external js that is downloaded with a dynamic name, if I move the bundle to the final location and I run it with Node, when it try to `require('dynamic_fullpath.js')`, the log tells `Error: Cannot find module dynamic_fullpath.js`, the file(in this case: dynamic_fullpath.js) exists in the right path.

I think the problem is: Webpack changes the **require js methods** to **require webpack methods** and when builds the bundle: the dynamic_fullpath.js does not exist and dont add to the bundle.

Any idea how to resolve this dynamic **require**?

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem as supposed: **Webpack changes the require js methods to require webpack methods and when builds the bundle: the dynamic_fullpath.js does not exist and dont add to the bundle**, so, to avoid that on an specific require I found this solution, and as the post said:

---

"

A simpler way to pull this off without resorting to eval is:

```
const requireFunc = typeof __webpack_require__ === "function" ? __non_webpack_require__ : require;
const foo = requireFunc(moduleName);
```

In the bundled output, this will become

```
const requireFunc = true ? require : require;
const foo = requireFunc(moduleName);
```

"

---

The solution was found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4175#issuecomment-342931035)